# Algorithm for Generating All Possible Arrangements of Widgets in a Grid

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, backtracking

I'm working on a problem where I need to generate all possible arrangements of a set of widgets in a grid. The grid has a fixed size of 15x7 (width x height). Each widget has a unique identifier and a set of possible sizes. The sizes are represented as (width, height) pairs.

Here's an example of the possible sizes for each widget:

```
{
"1": [(1, 1), (3, 1), (6, 3), (9, 6), (12, 7)],
"2": [(1, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (6, 3)],
// ... and so on for each widget
}
```

The widgets are initially arranged in a base template. Here's an example of a base template:

```
"template": [
        ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9"],
        ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9"],
        ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9"],
        ["2", "2", "2", "5", "5", "5", "8", "8", "8", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C"],
        ["2", "2", "2", "5", "5", "5", "8", "8", "8", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C"],
        ["3", "3", "3", "6", "6", "6", "8", "8", "8", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D"],
        ["4", "4", "4", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D"]
    ],
```

Each widget can be shrunk or enlarged. When a widget is shrunk, it should switch to the next smaller size in its list of possible sizes. When a widget is enlarged, it should switch to the next larger size. The surrounding widgets should adjust as well, but the total size of the grid should not exceed 15x7.

I'm looking for an algorithm that can generate all possible arrangements of the widgets in the grid, taking into account the possible sizes of each widget and the constraints of the grid size. I've considered using a backtracking algorithm, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have 15x7, or 105 slots. You have some N number of unique widgets (widget/size combination). So what you have is essentially a 105 digit number in base N. If N=10, then the number of possible arrangements is 10^104. That's an enormous number. You'd never be able to list all of the possible arrangements. As the number of widgets and sizes increases, so too does the complexity of the problem.

Comment: You're correct in pointing out the theoretical maximum number of arrangements. However, the actual problem has additional constraints that reduce the number of valid arrangements significantly. For instance, each widget can occupy multiple slots, and the size of the widget changes across all slots it occupies when it is enlarged or shrunk.

So, while the theoretical maximum is indeed N^105 (N=13), the actual number of valid arrangements is likely much smaller. That said, it's still a large number and finding all valid arrangements is a computationally intensive task.

Comment: I'm currently exploring more sophisticated algorithms such as recursive backtracking and dynamic programming to solve this problem.